# Коснтруктор перемещения для собственного класса Vector, который наследуется от std::array

Tags: c++, ооп

Я реализовываю шаблонный класс Vector, который наследуется от std::array. Вопрос: как я могу реализовать конструктор перемещения?

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
Vector<T, N>::Vector(Vector &&other)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        this->_M_elems[i] = other._M_elems[i];
    }

    // вот тут нужно отнять права у other
}
```

После того, как я скопировал данные, мне нужно отнять эти данные у other, верно? Если да, то как я могу это сделать? Заполнить его нулями не кажется мне выходом.

Comment: Гм. Если вы *копируете*, то зачем вам вообще конструктор *перемещения*? "Чтоб было"? Вообще-то перемещение - для эффективности, а не для лишней работы...

Comment: а как мне для такого класса реализовать конструктор перемещения? для какого-нибудь класса String, я бы просто перекинул указатель и скопировал размер. а что делать с std::array? как его перемещать?

Comment: Так он же хранит данные не в динамической памяти, тут быстрого переброса указателя не получится. Так что просто обходитесь одним копированием, без перемещения.

Comment: std::array не самый хороший вариант для реализации std::vector. Но просто не наследуйтесь, а храните внутри как указатель и все будет все просто.

Comment: задача стояла именно в наследовании от std::array

Comment: у std::array не виртуальный декструктор. бейте того, что Вам предложил такое задание. Да, можно взять приватно наследоваться, но нужно ли?

Comment: Конструктор с аргументом `Vector &&other` означает, что аргумент передан по ссылке, и его можно менять, и он обладает свойством, что потенциально он имеет время жизни очень маленькое. Конструктор имеет право модифицировать аргумент, путём обмена со своими указателями, но аргумент должен оставаться в ликвидном состоянии вплоть до своего его вызова деструктора. Обмен указателями приводит к большому преимуществу, так как обмен указателями намного быстрее, чем обмен данными. Но так-как у вас почему-то массив `std::array`, он не имеет возможности быстро сменить данные, у него **нет** указателей.

Comment: ... Конструктор перемещения не имеет смысл вообще писать, он будет идентичен конструктору копирования.

Comment: А вы точно *наследуете*? а то очень смущает - если наследуете! - вот эта вот запись: `this->_M_elems[i] = other._M_elems[i];` - что-то она наследованию не отвечает... Что это за член - `_M_elems`?

Comment: @Harry У `std::array` элементы хранятся в публичном (!) поле - сишном массиве. Без этого не работала бы инициализация фигурными скобками. Имя поля зависит от стандартной библиотеки, похоже.

Comment: @Gawain Я бы вместо `_M_elems` использовал `[]` - а то у вас код не переносимый...

Answer (score 1):

Реализовывать его самому не нужно.

Компилятор сам сгенерирует подходящий перемещающий конструктор, так же как и все остальные копирующие и перемещающие операции, и деструктор.

Общее правило: если можно их не писать, то лучше не писать их просто так. Это называют [**the rule of 0**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно будет вызвать перемещающий конструктор из базового класса, например:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class
t_Array
:   private ::std::array< ::std::unique_ptr< int >, 10 >
{
    public:
    t_Array(t_Array && other) noexcept
    :   array{::std::move(other)}
    {}
};
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aclass%0At_Array%0A:+++private+::std::array%3C+::std::unique_ptr%3C+int+%3E,+10+%3E%0A%7B%0A++++public:%0A++++t_Array(t_Array+%26%26+other)+noexcept%0A++++:+array%7B::std::move(other)%7D%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo(t_Array+%26%26+other)%0A%7B%0A++++t_Array+moved%7B::std::move(other)%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: а у std::array есть перемещающий конструктор?

Comment: Если для элементов array такой конструктор доступен, то и для самого array - тоже.

Comment: ага, похоже оно так и есть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613991/move-constructors-and-stdarray